# Files: getting rid of extra quotations and changing list to tuple for dictionary values

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, tuples

I'm taking a file that has the first line as a "header" of sorts to identify the strings and their placements in the remaining lines.

Example of what the file will contain:

```
"Headline","Newspaper", "Year Published", "Author"
"Crash", "New York Times", "2001", "Smith"
"Fire", "Washington Post", "2010", "Dudley"
"Addiction", "National Enquirer", "2008", "Kuhn"
```

I've achieved that the first string will be the key for my dictionary and the rest of the string will become the value for that key. For now my values in the dictionary are presenting themselves as a list. How can I change my code to have the value in the dictionary appear as a tuple instead? Also, my code is adding on an extra set of quotation marks onto my key and values and I have tried to get rid of them (seen below). Also I tried an if statement along with .isdigit() to identify and get rid of the quotation marks on all the numbers that will be a part of the value in the dictionary.

I keep on getting :

```
{'"Crash"':[' "New York Times"',' "2001"', '"Smith"'],
'"Fire"':[' "Washington Post"',' "2010"', '"Dudley"']} etc.
```

When I want:

```
{"Crash":( "New York Times", 2001, "Smith"),
"Fire":( "Washington Post", 2010, "Dudley")} etc.
```

My code:

```
def read_file(filename):
    d={}
    f= open(filename,"r")
    first_line = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip('"')
        data=line.split(",")
        key_data=data[0]
        values_data= data[1:5]
        valuesindate=tuple(values_data)
        d[key_data]=values_data
        tupval=tuple(d.values())
        for i in d.values():
            if i.isdigit():
                line=line.strip('"')
                line = line.split()
                line[-1] = line[-1].strip('"\n')
                floats = [float(i) for i in line]
            else:
               pass

        print(d)

read_file(".file0.csv")
```

Forgot to mention I'm limited (unfortunately) to not using the csv module. It would definitely make my life a whole lot easier.

Comment: Why don't you use instead `csv` module if you are reading a csv file?...It will save you the trouble trimming those "," and plus you are making the values of your dict. as lists through `values_data= data[1:5]` !

Comment: Unfortunately one of my limitations for this exorcise is to not import the csv module

Comment: You need to strip your space before you strip `"`

Comment: @Nick added an answer...

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Here 'a' is a line/row that you read from the file:

```
 a = '"Crash", "New York Times", "2001", "Smith"'
 a = a.replace('"', '')  # remove "
 a = a.split(',') #create list
 a = [int(i) if i.strip().isdigit() else i.strip() for i in a] # convert "2001" to 2001 in the list, this will take care of all such integers
 d[a[0]] = tuple(d[a[1:]])  # update your dict
```

I see that you are assigning the rest of the list here:

```
d[key_data]=values_data
```

If you want a tuple, you should be doing:

```
d[key_data]= tuple(values_data)
```

or since you already have

```
 valuesindate=tuple(values_data)
```

do

```
 d[key_data]= valuesindate
```

To get rid of the " around each element in the row string, you will need to do a string.replace() on the row string before splitting it

Comment: That definitely solved my list vs tuple dilemma, it definitely flew over my head. I'll work on what you suggested, but this would only get rid of the extra quotes around everything, right? After that, how would I get rid of the quotes just around the numerical items in my values?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this problem. You can remove the extraneous `"` characters and split each line on `', '` (comma followed by a space). Use tuple unpacking to assign each field to an appropriately named variable and then use those variables to construct a tuple for the dictionary.

```
def read_file(filename):
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        next(f)    # skip header row
        for line in f:
            headline, newspaper, year_published, author = line.strip().replace('"').split(', ')
            d[headline] = (newspaper, int(year_published), author)

    return d
```

You could also handle each line without unpacking into variables and use the first item of the split line as the key, however, unpacking into named variables provides a level of documentation and makes it very clear what is what, particularly when it comes to converting the year to an integer.